# I followed a CUDA tutorial but my GPU computation time is much longer than my CPU time?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I followed the tutorial on [this page](https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-lightning-fast-code-with-cuda-c18677dcdd5f) but my results are terrible. The time taken is as follows:

```
CPU: 569
GPU: 11160
```

Here is my code. What is going wrong? I can't see why this code is so slow?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void addCUDA(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

void add(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main()
{
    int N = 1 << 20;
    float* x = new float[N];
    float* y = new float[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    add(N, x, y);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;
    std::cout << duration << std::endl;
    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;

    float* u,
    float* v;
    cudaMallocManaged(&u, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&v, N * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        u[i] = 1.0f;
        v[i] = 2.0f;
    }
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    int device = -1;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(u, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(v, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);

    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    addCUDA<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>> (N, u, v);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t4 - t3).count();
    maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(v[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;
    std::cout << duration << std::endl;
    cudaFree(u);
    cudaFree(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to have a typo: `float* u,` that should be a semicolon.  Fixing that, when I run your code as-is on linux, V100 GPU, I get CPU: 972, GPU: 1085.  When I add the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after the prefetch calls, as suggested in the answer, I get CPU: 966, GPU: 193.  Furthermore, it seems likely you are on windows.  I would expect different behavior on windows.  GPU type matters, compilation type/project configuration matters, platform matters.

Answer (score 1):

For a so trivial operation (`+` on each element) it takes way more time to send the buffers from host to gpu and to retrieve the buffer from gpu to host, than performing the actual computation.
Even if the API is very comfortable to make buffer accesses look easy and almost magic, data has to travel through the PCI-express bus...
The transfer is asynchronous here, but the computation has to wait for it to complete before actually starting; asynchronous transfer is interesting only if you have something else to do in the meantime (organise various stages of a complex computation as a pipeline for example).

If you try with another problem that requires much more computation, the buffer transfers will be amortized.

Moreover, two arrays of `1<<20` `float`s requires *only* 8MB and can fit in the cache memory of a modern CPU.
Then, after the initialisation of these two arrays, they may be already *hot* in cache memory and easily accessible for CPU computation.
Because the computation is a perfectly regular loop, a decent optimizing compiler will use SIMD instructions, the CPU won't mispredict branches and will perfectly prefetch the data in the various cache levels; all of this greatly increases CPU efficiency for this kind of computation.

It's not so easy to outperform a modern CPU with a GPU.
It really depends on the size and the complexity of the problem (an on the specific properties of these two pieces of hardware of course).

---

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comments, the timing method used in the cited article and the one shown in the question are very different.

In the article, `nvprof` uses internal counters in the GPU to measure the time spent actively computing the `addCUDA()` (`add()` in the article) function, without considering either the time it takes to obtain the two source buffers from host and to send back the resulting buffer to host.
Of course, it's fast! Because on much modern hardware (CPU or GPU) most of the time is spent accessing/transferring data rather than computing. If we measured the time spent in our CPU to perform additions **only**, ignoring the time spent fetching/writing data from/to cache/memory, it would not be very long either!
(Note that the CPU code in the article is not even compiled with optimisation turned on; do such timings have any meaning?)

In the code shown in the question, the timing method is quite different but much more relevant in my opinion.
The two calls to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` actually consider the time spent doing **all** the work: sending the two source buffers, computing on them and fetching the resulting buffer.
It's the only duration that matters after all!
This way, it is fair to compare this duration to the one we obtain (with a similar method) when timing the CPU.

The fact that `cudaMemPrefetchAsync()` is used can be misleading because we could think that the transfer of the source buffers is excluded from the timings: it is not, and that's why we find the result disappointing compared to the article.
We launch the timer right after these two calls in order to measure the time spent in the computation, but the computation has to wait for these transfers to complete before actually starting (I would even have started the timer *before* these two calls).
Moreover, the call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before stopping the timer waits for the transfer of the resulting buffer to complete in order to actually make the result available to the host.
If we used `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before starting the timer, we could have excluded the two initial transfers from the timing, but what's the point of such a timing?

In conclusion, I think the timing method you used in your question is much better than the one promoted in the article since you can really compare the benefit you obtain (or not!) from one technology over the other.

For information, on my computers, with full optimisation turned on, your code gives these results:

```
CPU: 809   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz]
GPU: 1160  NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)

CPU: 157   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10875H CPU @ 2.30GHz
GPU: 1158  NVIDIA Corporation TU104GLM [Quadro RTX 4000 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

Comment: The code presented is designed with the intent that the cost of the buffer transfers is not included in the measurement.

Comment: @RobertCrovella it is however. The transfer is asynchronous but the timing starts immediately and the computation just has to wait for the transfer to complete before actually starting. We could have performed a synchronous transfer and start timing right after, but that would have been cheating ;^)

Comment: so maybe it would be good to suggest putting a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before the start of the timing region.  I'm reasonably sure the **intent** of the code writer was to not time the transfer cost.  Yes, it may contain a bug in this respect.  If so, pointing it out may be helpful.